# send a get http request by axios on react to laravel 10 backend on localhost

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, cors

i am using axios on react to send http request to laravel backend. but cors prevent laravel to answer my request. i catch below error:

p://localhost/todo/laravel/public/api/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

my react code:

```
    axios.get('http://localhost/todo/laravel/public/api/test', { withCredentials: true })
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
            // always executed
        });
```

my laravel code:

```
public function all(): bool|string
{
    $todos = Todo::all();
    return json_encode($todos);
}
```

my cors config:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
| or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
| in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
|
| To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
|
*/
'paths' => ['*'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => false,

'max_age' => false,

'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

what is problem?

Comment: how about if you include the port in your url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
'paths' => ['todo/*'],

I' not sure, that ['*'] is allowed